# Find child elements in table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
    TABLE
=======================

ID      NAME    PARENT_ID
1       AAA     -1
2       BBB     -1
3       CCC     -1
4       DDD     -1
5       EEE     -1
100     AX      1
200     BX      1
1001    L1      100
1002    L2      100
1003    L3      100
1004    L4      100
2001    L1      200
2002    L2      200
2003    L3      200
2004    L4      200
10010   P1      1001
10011   P2      1001
20010   P3      2001
20011   P4      2001
```

TABLE - actually tree of projects in the hierarchy. 
Projects with Parent_id -1 are root elements, 
other projects refer to its parent by parent__id

> I'd like to create a function which you calls with input array/table
> of numbers in my case int (id) and it returns table/array of child
> elements
>
> for instance
> FIND_LEAFS(INPUT table of int) 
> and it returns its child elements - by making 
> e.g. select id from TABLE where parent_id in (INPUT) 
> I will then inserting returned id in some table (if not zero) and call 
> FIND_LEAFS again with the result as input until zero children found.

> e.g. if I call for the first time with an array of one element (id=1) 
> FIND_LEAFS(1)  - it should return ids 100,200 (it has parent_id = 1) 
> I insert it to some table or array. 
> then I call it again with the result as input.

> FIND_LEAFS(100,200) - it should return ids (10001,1002,1003,1004,2001,2002,2003,20004) 
> Then I called it again with returns as input.

> FIND_LEAFS(10001,1002,1003,1004,2001,2002,2003,20004) 
> This returns zero array cuz it has no child elements.
> The level of child is deeper in reality but it doesnt matter.

I can't figure it out. Tried function with input and output array (type table of number) 
but wasn't successful.
Any suggestion or example is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: A leaf in a tree is a node that doesn't have children. So, just for starters, why is a function that gets the immediate children (not the leaf descendants) called "FIND_LEAFS"?

Comment: Also note that the common practice (at least in Oracle) is to have `null` parent for the roots (rather than `-1`).

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a function and can use hierarchical queries:

#### Find the children:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  parent_id = 1
```

Outputs:

> | ID | NAME | PARENT_ID |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 100 | AX | 1 |
> | 200 | BX | 1 |

#### Find all the descendents:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
START WITH id = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
```

Outputs:

> | ID | NAME | PARENT_ID |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | AAA | -1 |
> | 100 | AX | 1 |
> | 1001 | L1 | 100 |
> | 10010 | P1 | 1001 |
> | 10011 | P2 | 1001 |
> | 1002 | L2 | 100 |
> | 1003 | L3 | 100 |
> | 1004 | L4 | 100 |
> | 200 | BX | 1 |
> | 2001 | L1 | 200 |
> | 20010 | P3 | 2001 |
> | 20011 | P4 | 2001 |
> | 2002 | L2 | 200 |
> | 2003 | L3 | 200 |
> | 2004 | L4 | 200 |

#### Find all the leaf descendents:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH id = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
```

Outputs:

> | ID | NAME | PARENT_ID |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 10010 | P1 | 1001 |
> | 10011 | P2 | 1001 |
> | 1002 | L2 | 100 |
> | 1003 | L3 | 100 |
> | 1004 | L4 | 100 |
> | 20010 | P3 | 2001 |
> | 20011 | P4 | 2001 |
> | 2002 | L2 | 200 |
> | 2003 | L3 | 200 |
> | 2004 | L4 | 200 |

---

If you did want to wrap one of those queries into a function then you can do:

```sql
CREATE TYPE int_list IS TABLE OF INT;

CREATE FUNCTION find_leaves(
  ids IN int_list
) RETURN int_list
IS
  v_leaves int_list;
BEGIN
  SELECT id
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_leaves
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
  START WITH id MEMBER OF ids
  CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id;

  RETURN v_leaves;
END find_leaves;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(find_leaves(int_list(100, 200)));
```

Outputs:

> | COLUMN_VALUE |
> | --- |
> | 10010 |
> | 10011 |
> | 1002 |
> | 1003 |
> | 1004 |
> | 20010 |
> | 20011 |
> | 2002 |
> | 2003 |
> | 2004 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=73c047453ffbff3f4c591f130b1f60de)*